# How to fix problem with usage: dirname path?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm not too sure what caused the issue. I can't remember if this happened after I installed node or after I used time machine when setting up my new Mac. Either way, I'm getting this "usage: dirname path" in my terminal and I'm not too sure how set it back to normal.

I've gone through some stackoverflow solutions but I don't understand what I should do. I can code but I've never touched the bashprofile before.

When opening the terminal, I should see the following only:

Before:

```
usage: dirname path
usage: dirname path
(base) Shivas-MacBook-Pro:~ shivaSkanthan$
```

After:

```
(base) Shivas-MacBook-Pro:~ shivaSkanthan$
```

Comment: Check your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files.  `grep dirname $HOME/.bash*`.

Comment: How do I open the .bash_profile? I'm really new to doing this so apologies for the asking simple questions.

Comment: Okay I found both files. This is in the bashrc file. Not too sure what to look for though:
`# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this link on [stackoverflow](https://superuser.com/questions/498312/how-to-reset-bash-on-mac-osx-bash-profile-corrupted-and-bash-no-longer-works) solved my problem.

I basically typed this in terminal `/usr/bin/nano .bash_profile` and removed some junk and the terminal is looking well again.

Comment: Hi, how do you finally config that? I got the same error.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I just went to `/usr/bin/nano .bash_profile` and deleted some of the node related code inside. You can try using that line of code and sharing a screenshot and I can help you debug, hopefully.